# apt-get update fails on live USB session

Tags: apt, live-usb

When I run `sudo apt-get update` from a default live USB session (Ubuntu Desktop 17.10) why do I get this error?

```
Ign:1 cdrom://Ubuntu 17.10 _Artful Aardvark_ - Release amd64 (20180105.1) artful InRelease
Hit:2 cdrom://Ubuntu 17.10 _Artful Aardvark_ - Release amd64 (20180105.1) artful Release
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main Translation-en_GB [71.1 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/restricted Translation-en_GB [2,464 B]
Fetched 73.6 kB in 0s (216 kB/s)           
Reading package lists... Done
W: chown to _apt:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (95: Operation not supported)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (95: Operation not supported)
W: chown to root:root of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_InRelease failed - 201::URIDone (95: Operation not supported)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_InRelease failed - 201::URIDone (95: Operation not supported)
```

When I run `ls -al /var/lib/apt/lists/`, it shows

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ls -al /var/lib/apt/lists/
total 12285
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     140 Feb 14 21:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      80 Feb 14 21:57 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  236651 Oct 19 12:56 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6681096 Oct 19 12:56 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_main_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3402759 Oct 16 10:08 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_main_i18n_Translation-en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  110861 Oct 19 12:56 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   18974 Oct 13 11:12 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful_restricted_i18n_Translation-en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   78587 Jan  5 20:32 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-updates_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  866650 Jan  5 18:44 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  462155 Jan  5 06:05 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   19723 Nov 10 14:56 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3724 Nov  8 21:27 archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-updates_restricted_i18n_Translation-en
-rw-r----- 1 root root       0 Jan  5 20:35 lock
drwx------ 1 _apt root      40 Feb 14 21:57 partial
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   78589 Jan  5 20:32 security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-security_InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  347191 Jan  5 11:18 security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-security_main_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  202149 Jan  4 16:16 security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_artful-security_main_i18n_Translation-en
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   48945 Feb 14 21:57 Ubuntu%2017.10%20%5fArtful%20Aardvark%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20180105.1)_dists_artful_main_binary-amd64_Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3355 Feb 14 21:57 Ubuntu%2017.10%20%5fArtful%20Aardvark%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20180105.1)_dists_artful_Release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     819 Feb 14 21:57 Ubuntu%2017.10%20%5fArtful%20Aardvark%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20180105.1)_dists_artful_Release.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4629 Feb 14 21:57 Ubuntu%2017.10%20%5fArtful%20Aardvark%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20180105.1)_dists_artful_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages
```

The exist code returned is 100 (as given by `echo $?`) which indicates an error.

The reason I thought this was a problem for me was due to the next command failing too. I was running `apt-get install some-package-i-wanted` and got the error 'Unable to locate package'. So I assumed the first error was the root cause. However, it turns out the package isn't available on the default repositories for version 17.10.

I got round the problem by downloading and installing the .deb package manually from the relevant website.

Still interested to understand what the original error message means though.

Comment: Same issue here ! with Ubuntu Desktop 17.10 from a live usv key

Comment: Could you please send the result of `ls -al /var/lib/apt/lists/` ? And is this blocking, because it looks like a warning, not an error.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error per se. Are you prevented from doing anything?